Intersection between hyperrectangle and region $x_1+x_2+...+x_n \geq s$
I'm looking for an algorithm that finds the volume of the intersection between a hyperrectangle (n-dimensional polytope with all right angles) and the plane $x_1+x_2+...+x_n \geq s$, given the dimensions $d_1,d_2,...,d_n$ of the polytope and the parameter $s$. The polytope is assumed to have one of its vertices placed at the origin, and to be entirely contained in the non-negative region of coordinate space.
Alternatively, this could be modeled as a probability problem, with the goal of finding the probability that the sum of $n$ independent uniformly distributed variables, with intervals $[0,d_1],...,[0,d_n]$, add up to at least $s$ (with the result multiplied by $\prod_{i = 1}^{n} d_{i}$ for equivalence with the geometric formulation).
So far I've found solutions for the cases where $n=2$ or $n=3$, as detailed below, but I haven't been able to generalize any further. (The solutions assume that $d_1 \leq d_2 \leq d_3$ and $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} d_{i} \geq  s/2$, since other cases can be mapped to these by reordering or inverting the variables.)
$$f_{\text{2}}(d_1, d_2, s) = 
\begin{cases} 
0 & \text{if } s \geq d_1 + d_2 \\
\frac{1}{2} \cdot \text{side}^2 & \text{if } s \geq d_2 \\
\frac{1}{2} \cdot \left( \text{side}^2 - \text{x_cutoff}^2 \right) & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}\\
\text{where:}\\
\text{side} = d_1 + d_2 - s\\
\text{x_cutoff} = d_2 - s\\$$
$$f_{\text{3}}(d_1, d_2, d_3, s) = 
\begin{cases} 
0 & \text{if } s \geq d_1 + d_2 + d_3 \\
\frac{1}{6} \cdot \text{side}^3 & \text{if } s \geq d_2 + d_3 \\
\frac{1}{6} \cdot \left( \text{side}^3 - \text{x_cutoff}^3 \right) & \text{if } s \geq d_1 + d_3 \\
\frac{1}{6} \cdot \left( \text{side}^3 - \text{x_cutoff}^3 - \text{y_cutoff}^3 \right) & \text{if } s \geq d_1 + d_2 \text{ and } s \geq d_3 \\
\frac{1}{6} \cdot \left( \text{side}^3 - \text{x_cutoff}^3 - \text{y_cutoff}^3 - \text{z_cutoff}^3 \right) & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}\\
\text{where:}\\
\text{side} = d_1 + d_2 + d_3 - s\\
\text{x_cutoff} = d_2 + d_3 - s\\
\text{y_cutoff} = d_1 + d_3 - s\\
\text{z_cutoff} = d_1 + d_2 - s$$

You are on an interesting track. The $1/2$ and $1/6$ suggest that the general formula will have a factor $1/n!$, and that each case is the volume of a pyramid. In higher dimensions the region may not be a pyramid. Can you list the cases for $n=4$?

$s\geq d_2 + d_3\implies s\geq d_1+d_2.$ Did you mean to make the cases disjoint ? Seems like you can write the general formula for $n=3$ as:
$$6V = \text{side}^3 - \sum_{v\in{x,y,z}}\text{v}{\text{cutoff}}^3\cdot \mathbb{1}{{\text{v cutoff >0}}}$$

Yes, the cases are disjoint.
For n=4, I've tried adding a $+d_4$ term to each of the $n=3$ cases and then another case where $s \geq d_1+d_2+d_3$, but that doesn't seem to be enough. From my tests, it works when $d_1=d_2=d_3=d_4$, but the result gets more and more off as the difference between the variables increases. The factorial pattern seems to indeed be correct, though.
